# Tesseract DoOcr method exits the application

Tags: c#, ocr, tesseract, automatic-license-plate-recognition

Hi guys I am new to OCR and Tesserect as well. I was trying to do an OCR on an image but my application keeps exiting when I try to reach this particular line

```
ocrText = ocr.DoOCR(npList[1], plateList[1]);
```

Previously it threw an exception saying it requires additional configuration and I updated the App.Config file but now the application exits at this line of code.

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to sort this out guys it was something to do with my training data!

Comment: Can you tell us what was wrong with your data please ? (if you remember..)

Comment: I'm sorry @MickaelV. it has been a long time and I don't remember the issue I had!